# Using the address of a public member variable to access a private member

Tags: c++, pointers, memory-management

I created the following simple test program to show that I can use the address of public integer to access the value of a private integer:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class CarType{
  public:
    int year;
    CarType(int price, int year){this -> year = year; this -> price = price;};
  private: 
    int price;
};

int main(){
  //Create new CarType object
  CarType a = CarType(15000, 1999);
  //Increment the memory address of public member variable, year by 1 and save the result
  int* pricePointer = &a.year+1;
  //De-reference the memory address and output it
  cout << "PRICE: "<< *pricePointer << endl;
  return 0;
}
```

The output shows that I can access the price variable just by knowing the address of year. Is there a way to prevent against this? Is this just an edge case or is this true for all types of objects?

Comment: C++ won't prevent someone from shotting himeself in the foot.

Comment: There is *no* guarantee that what you are doing will always work. Essentially, in this case, the compiler has laid out the memory in such a way that the variable `price` is placed "just after" `year`. But because you are using a class and not a POD, and the compiler does "add stuff" to the object, there is no guarantee that the memory will always be laid out this way. Try adding other member variables and methods and see what happens. See Item 11 of C++ Common Knowledge by Stephen C. Dewhurst for details. Others who are more familiar with compiler designs might be able to provide more details.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is *possibly* undefined (but certainly unwise) behaviour and you can prevent it in much the same way you prevent people writing to random addresses, or prevent inexperienced people from cutting off limbs with a chainsaw. In other words, not at all.

Caveat Coder.

The reason I say *possibly* in the above paragraph is that it's not entirely clear. In language-lawyer terms, refer to `C++14 5.7 Additive operators /4`:

> For the purposes of these operators, a pointer to a nonarray object behaves the same as a pointer to the first element of an array of length one with the type of the object as its element type.

and `/5` when discussing adding an integral value to a pointer:

> If both the pointer operand and the result point to elements of the same array object, or one past the last element of the array object, the evaluation shall not produce an overflow; otherwise, the behavior is undefined.

In your case, your pointer is actually pointing "one past the last element" so the addition itself doesn't generate undefined behaviour.

You may think that dereferencing the object would be undefined but, as per a note in `3.9.2 Compound types /3`, it appears it may be valid:

> For instance, the address one past the end of an array (5.7) would be considered to point to an unrelated object of the array’s element type that might be located at that address.

However, undefined or not, it's still unwise to dereference since you don't actually *know* that there is a variable of the correct type there. Implementations are free to pad structures as they see fit so there's no guarantee that `price` will be the same as `*(year + 1)`.

Comment: Could this be a security issue if I had access to the source-code of the library I was implementing? (e.g. A poorly written password validation function)

Comment: @isquaredr [Is Encapsulation a security device?](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/classes-and-objects#encap-is-not-security)

Comment: @isquaredr That would be a far bigger issue if you did *not* have `access to the source-code of the library I was implementing` ;-) I think you need to elaborate what "*security issue*" you might be concerned about.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie that is a very good point and is exactly what I was looking for. Based on lectures I had the understanding that `private` was a way to secure data.

Comment: @isquaredr, `private` is a way to secure data from the developer that follows the rules and it works, as evidenced by the fact trying to access a private member will refuse to compile. It does not protect from end-runs around such protection. You can always do those but the upshot is: it may or may not work.