# Get private element outside the class

Tags: c++, scope, encapsulation

First of all it's an exercise given to me so i can't change things and have to work with it.
I have a 2d vector aka a matrix. My header file looks like this

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
class Matrix{
private:
vector<vector<double>> 2d;
public:
explicit Matrix(unsigned int sizeY=0,unsigned int sizeX=0,double value= 0.0);
~Matrix() = default;
Matrix(const Matrix &other);
Matrix(Matrix &&other) = default;
Matrix& operator=(const Matrix &other);
Matrix& operator=(Matrix &&other) = default;


//other + - operators

//INDEX
vector<double>& at(unsigned int i);
const vector<double>& at(unsigned int i)const;

const vector<double>& operator[] (double m) const;
vector<double>& operator[] (double m);
};

Matrix operator+(const Matrix& d1, const Matrix& d2);

Matrix operator-(const Matrix& d1, const Matrix& d2);


ostream& operator<<(ostream &o, const Matrix& v);
istream& operator>>(istream &i, Matrix& v);
```

So now I implemented everything except the << and >> operator.
Now the question if i want to go through the 2d vec matrix is there another way to get the "depth"
outside the Matrix class except writing a getter ?
If the Matrix is N X M e.g. 4x4 i can get the 2nd 4 the "width" with something like 2d[0].size() but i cant figure out how I can get the "depth" otherwise then use a getter.
Also i cant change 2d to public or use templates.

I tried for around 2-3 hours myself and couldnt find any solution and maybe its not possible under the given conditions.

Comment: `vector<vector<double>> 2d;` will not compile.

Comment: Have you tried compiling this exact code?  It's curious that you're asking how to add to code that already won't compile.

Comment: Maybe you need to declare operator<< as friend, [reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2828280/friend-functions-and-operator-overloading-what-is-the-proper-way-to-overlo )

Comment: If you have asked your teacher, he answered that there is no problem with all the interfaces inside the class, maybe you can try some [hack methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37981617/using-the-address- of-a-public-member-variable-to-access-a-private-member)

Comment: Why would you want to write `matrix_name.elements[0].size()` instead of `matrix_name.columns()`?

Comment: vector<vector<double>> 2d; should be vector<vector<double>> matrix; my bad ;)

Comment: @Kargath if i declare it as a friend then i need to move it inside the class in header and cpp file and work as usual ? Is it common pratice ?

Comment: You need to add the friend `keyword` for `operator<<` in the declaration of the class, and you don't need to add it for the definition in the `*.cpp` file.
[This link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2828320/13792395) mentions "Since the stream operators' left-hand argument is a stream, stream operators either have to be members of the stream class or free functions. "

Comment: @Kargath ok maybe i dont get something but i used to keyword and let << outside my Matrix class and done nothing in the cpp diff but now i get the "friend used outside the class " error.The Line in the Headerfile looks like that: friend ostream& operator<<(ostream &o, const Matrix& v);

Comment: I mean, you should add `friend` at the declaration of `operator<<` in `class`, like [this](https://github.com/KargathEx/Thinking-In-C-resource/blob/master/Resource/C12/IostreamOperatorOverloading.cpp#L23)

Comment: @Kargath I think i got it now ;) so In the class friend ostream& operator<<(ostream &o, const Matrix& v); then outside the class (but in header ) i dont change anything and same for cpp file. Yeah Kargath thank you for your time mate

Comment: Yes, you don't need to add friend keyword outside of class

Answer (score 0):

2d[0].size() is giving you the length of the first vector stored in 2d. To get the length of 2d you can just call the same directly on 2d.

2d.size() = length of 2d
2d[0].size() = length of first vector stored in 2d

Comment: if i try to use v.size() inside  ostream& operator<<(ostream &o, const Matrix& v) i get  the "has no member named size" error

Comment: V is a reference to a matrix class. Are you trying to get the depth of 2d?